# Edit user privileges for database via ssh and no root

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin

I installed phpMyAdmin on a Raspberry that I can (want) only access via ssh (It's also a media server behind the TV, that's why). I have the root access disabled but I created an user with `ALL PRIVILEGES` and `GRANT`. The problem is, I can not grant privileges on a DB for other users via ssh.

What am I missing?

[image: Capture users table for a DB]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did everything ok. Apparently the server needed some time to digest the new information. (I had `FLUSH`ed privileges).